# MySQL 8+ JSON Query to extract one value from an array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, select

I'm trying all sort of possibilities to extract a single element in a JSON column that contains an array. Let me give the example:

```
Database:
id | info
---------
1  |{"name": "aaa", "colors": ["a","b"]}
2  |{"name": "bbb", "colors": ["c","d"]}
3  |{"name": "ccc", "colors": ["e","f"]}
```

What I need is to have a similar query, like:
`select name, color from info where color = a;`

And this should return:
`"aaa", "a"`

The problem that I'm stuck is that I cannot search in the array without a fix index, but I need to be able to query the database without fix index.

Comment: Consider to use a relational design, when you use a relational database system.

Comment: *And this should return: "aaa", "a"* What is the point of output a well-known literal `"a"` that is used as the filtering condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_search()`:

```
select info ->> '$.name' as name, 'a' color
from mytable 
where json_search(info ->> '$.colors', 'one', 'a') is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT info->"$.name" AS `name`
FROM test
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(info, '"a"', '$.colors');
```